# How can I search a fixed and case insensitive string pattern in an array in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, case-sensitive

I want to make a perl script to take a list of values (the keys in a hash) and search it in an Array. I need to search the fixed pattern, but it can be case insensitive. This is my code:

```
foreach my $element ( keys %data ) {
    # this line search the exact pattern, but it isn't case insensitive
    if ( first { $element eq $_ } @database_lines ) {
        $counter += 1;
        print "$element\n";
    } else {
        next;
    }
}
```

Some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably create a hash of the lower-cased `@database_lines` content, and then look-up in that:

```
my %db_lines;
$db_lines{lc $_} = 1 for @database_lines;

foreach my $element (keys %data) {
    if ($db_lines{lc $element}) {
        $counter++;
        print "$element\n";
    }
}
```

If your Perl is new enough, you could use [fc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html) instead of [lc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html) to provide more accurate case-insensitive matching.

Comment: First two lines as one line: `my %db_lines = map { lc($_) => 1 } @database_lines;`.

Answer (score 2):

This will check using "contains" condition:

```
@f = grep /\Q$element\E/i, @lines;
print $f[0];
```

If you need an exact match, use:

```
@f = grep /^\Q$element\E\z/i, @lines;
print $f[0];
```

Comment: So you're saying change `first { $element eq $_ }` to `first { /^\Q$element\E$/i }`

Comment: @ikegami - Please explain a necessity of quoting. If you can't, please return everything to the original answer (removing brackets is OK). Here is an example that can help: $e='/';@f = grep /$e/i, ('/');print $f[0];

Comment: `$element = 'a*b'; $element =~ /$element/i` is false, so `/$element/i` doesn't check if `$element` is contained in `$_`. `$element = 'a*b'; $element =~ /^$element$/i` is false, so `/^$element$/i` doesn't check if `$_` is equal to `$element`. Thus my fixes.

Comment: You're saying "$element =~ /$element/i is false", but the code below prints '1': perl -e '$element = "a*b"; print ($element =~ /$element/i);'

Comment: Sorry, bad example. Use `$element = "ab*c";`

Comment: Interesting. I still don't understand why, but thank you for this great example. I'll keep the quoting in the answer :)

Comment: `/ab*c/` matches strings that contain `a` followed by 0 or more `b` followed by `c`. `ab*c` doesn't contain such a sequence. // `/\Qab*c/` aka `/ab\*c/` matches strings that contain `a` followed by `b` followed by `*` followed by `c`. `ab*c` contains such a sequence.

Comment: OK, got it. I didn't realize that what's inside variable is interpreted as an regex. I though, it would take it literally.

Comment: If it was automatically quoted, you couldn't build a pattern dynamically. e.g. `m{http://$host_pat...}`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend do this task in this way

```perl
use v5.16;
my $count = do {
    my %hash;
    @hash{map fc, @database_lines} = ();
    grep exists $hash{fc($_)}, keys %data;
};
```

The advantage is that this code is `O(M+N)` instead of `O(M*N)` of your original approach.